# Badge value always returns 0 using Parse in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, push-notification

I am using Parse Push notification for IOS. When using

```
  PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
```

CurrentInstallation has a valid data with all information in installation table but the badge value is always 0, but when I have checked in parse website, it has the value greater than 0.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:_deviceToken];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

if you delete an installation on your Parse web console this happens. To avoid this, you need to uninstall and reinstall the application on your phone, and it should start working again